# Escape characters appearing in an array with the `p` method without interpolation

Tags: ruby, string, interpolation, string-interpolation

For `overflow` below, the quotes are surrounding an array.

```
overflow = [5,6,7]
p overflow       #=> [5, 6, 7]
p "#{overflow}"  #=> "[5, 6, 7]"
```

For `stack` below, the results are strange for the interpolated expression.

```
stack = 1234.to_s.chars.reverse.each_slice(3).map { |s| s.reverse.join }.reverse
p stack          #=> ["1", "234"]
p "#{stack}"     #=> "[\"1\", \"234\"]"
```

How does the `p` method show escape characters with `stack`, but not with `overflow`? Why does this occur only with interpolation as opposed to when printed without interpolation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`overflow` is an array of integers while `stack` is an array of strings. There's nothing to escape in `overflow`.

Possibly you meant to make `stack` an array of `Fxinum` as well, in which case add `.map(&:to_i)` at the end of the method chain:

```
stack = 1234.to_s.chars.reverse.each_slice(3).map { |s| s.reverse.join }.reverse.map(&:to_i)
```

---

For the second question, that's how the method `p` works. To ge precise, the behavior is defined in [`String#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-inspect) as that's the method `p` is using:

> Returns a printable version of str, surrounded by quote marks, with special characters escaped.